# How do I unit test Named Configurations for Object Marshallers

Tags: grails, spock

I have a controller that uses named configuration for object marshallers

```
JSON.use( isAdmin ? 'adminApi' : 'publicApi') {
    respond book
}
```

How do I unit test above line of code using grails spock framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the book: [unit testing controllers](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers) and [content negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation) in *Testing Content Negotiation* (you have to scroll a bit to reach that section).

Like this:

```
@TestFor(FooController)
@Mock(Foo)
class FooControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def setup () {
       //... setup custom marshaller ...
    }

    // format parameter, assert on string response

    def "responds with admin result using format" () {
        when:
        params.isAdmin = true
        params.format='json'
        controller.foo()

        then:
        response.text == '{"something":"something"}'
    }

    // or using accept header, assert on parsed json    

    def "responds with admin result using accept header" () {
        when:
        params.isAdmin = true
        request.addHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        controller.foo()

        then:
        def json = response.json
        json.something == 'something'
    }
}
```